# Terraform Cloudfront InvalidViewerCertificate

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudfront

Im trying to create a Cloudform distribution using an existing ACM Certificate:

```
data "aws_acm_certificate" "issued" {
  domain = "*.mydomain.com"
  statuses = ["ISSUED"]
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "cloudfront" {
...

  viewer_certificate {
      cloudfront_default_certificate = false
      acm_certificate_arn = data.aws_acm_certificate.issued.id
      minimum_protocol_version = "TLSv1.1_2016"
      ssl_support_method = "sni-only"
  }
...
}
```

I'm getting the error: **Error: error updating CloudFront Distribution (EMLDE0O3OG6CZ): InvalidViewerCertificate: The specified SSL certificate doesn't exist, isn't in us-east-1 region, isn't valid, or doesn't include a valid certificate chain.**

The certificate is already in use with another manually created distribution, also when I replace `data.aws_acm_certificate.issued.id` by the certificate ARN as a string everything works fine.

Comment: Can you `output` the value of `data.aws_acm_certificate.issued.id` and verify that it has correct ARN (the one you are manually setting up)?

Comment: Are you creating that CloudFront distribution in `us-east-1`? Your data source for the certificate needs to be pointing at `us-east-1` so if your default AWS provider is trying to create the CloudFront distribution in another region then you will hit that error if you have a matching ACM cert in the other region.

Comment: @Marcin yes I've compared the output and it was exactly the same

Comment: @ydaetskcoR the certificate is on us-east-1 but the distribution is being created on a different region

Comment: What do you mean that distro is in different region? CF is global service, and does not have regions.

Comment: yes my bad, it is global @Marcin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so looking a bit closer I've realised that the certificate was coming from the region that I'm deploying my resources and not **"us-east-1"**

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45030925/4663041), this is how I've fixed the problem:

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = var.aws_region
}

provider "aws" {
  alias = "virginia"
  region = "us-east-1"
}

data "aws_acm_certificate" "issued" {
  domain   = "*.example.com"
  statuses = ["ISSUED"]
  provider = aws.virginia
}
```

According with [Terraform's docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/providers/configuration.html#default-provider-configurations), the provider without an alias is the default and I'll use the second only to fetch my certificate data!